# Proof of sphere in 3-space

Tags: linear-algebra

Thanks for reading. I have the following question as part of my math module on linear algebra.

"Let $u$ and $v$ be non-zero vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ in standard position. Prove that if $u$ and $v$ are of length $r$ cm each, where $r\in \mathbb{R}$ and $r > 0$, then their tips lie on the surface of a sphere of radius $r$ cm?"

It's obvious to me that it is true because I can picture it in my head but don't know how to go about proving it. Since it is an introductory question I don't think it requires a complex proof. Should I use an equation for a sphere, Pythagoras or would I simple sketch be sufficient? This question forms part of a formal assignment so I'm only looking to be put on the right track. Thanks.

Comment: This question you quoted is not a great question, but they probably want you  to write a vector in components and use the length formula you have and then do algebra until you get a recognizable equation for a sphere. I don't know why there are two vectors.

Comment: Thanks, Mark. That was my feeling as well. In general the subject isn't very well presented at the university. And for distance learning it is especially poor. I feel I have a decent grip on the topic but this question is just vague. Thanks again.